# How to use smartsheet API to get sheets which are upload by others

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am new to smart sheet. I need to use smart sheet API inside an Node Application to get sheets which are being uploaded by a user. I have gone through the documentation of smart sheet API. Document says to call API first need to get auth code which requires client_id. After getting auth code, need to get token.

I am not sure if I need to contact that user to get client Id or need to create new account. What should be my next step.

Answer (score 0):

Having others use your application to get their data would require you to have them login to your app using their Smartsheet credentials. Then as the requests are made they can be done as that user. This is can be done by implementing the Smartsheet OAuth flow. There is more information on this in the [Third-party App Development](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#third-party-app-development) section of our API docs.
If you are using Node.js you can see a simple implementation of using our SDK on Github [here](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/node-read-write-sheet).
As for the OAuth flow there is also an example of implementing that in Node.js on the [Smartsheet Samples Github](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/oauth-flow-sample-node).

Comment: But I am not creating any app where user can login. I am creating a Node Js job which will call Smart Sheet API to fetch data from smart sheet.

Comment: How are you getting the access token for the requests you are making? Are you generating a token in your account and setting that as an environment variable? The requests will only operate with the privileges of the access token being used in the request, so you could make sure the account you get the token from has access to all of the necessary sheets. Otherwise, you'll to implement the login for a user to authorize the use of their credentials in the requests.